# Графический редактор

Tags: графика, дизайн, редактор

В чём лично вы рисуете макет будущего сайта, и в чём потом рисуете кнопочки и прочие кубики дизайна? Я так обнаружил, что для этих задач больше подходит векторный редактор, я прав? И если да, то какой удобнее(именно для тех двух задач, которые я описал выше). Конечно понимаю, что это дело привычки, но всё же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял о чём вы, если о прототипах, то используем для прототипирования как сайтов, так и мобильных приложений WireframeSketcher (http://wireframesketcher.com/). На выходе имеем интерактивный кликабельный скетч-прототип.

Comment: я хотел узнать, какие графические редакторы предпочитаю веб-дизайнеры для разработки самого внешнего вида сайта(между тем, как представить в голове и превратить в код.) также хочу спросить, какой редактор лучше подходит для того, чтобы нарисовать кнопки, значки, пиктограммы..